# ThreadPool implemented with OpenMP

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, openmp

I need to implement a thread pool executor for generic tasks. My idea is to use OpenMP for thread management. The problem is that I'm not familar yet with OpenMP..

I tried to find an existing implementation of the generic ThreadPool with OpenMP, but I haven't find one so far. What I would like to have in the end is something very similar to `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
template <typename Return, typename Task>
class ThreadPoolExecutor
{
public:
    ThreadPoolExecutor(int threadCount);

    // asyncronous invoke
    boost::unique_future<Return> submit(const TaskPtr & task);

    // blocking call
    std::vector<Return> invokeAll(const std::vector<TaskPtr> & tasks)
    {
        // submit all tasks + wait for completion
        #pragma omp parallel default(shared)
        {
            // call tasks here
        }
    }
};
```

I have several questions about this approach:

1. Is there existing implementation of thread pool with OpenMP for C++? [I know I can implement threadpool with boost::asio::io_service, but I would prefer not depend on it]
2. With my design - how can we guarantee that the OpenMP threads will be 'owned' by the concrete ThreadPoolExecutor instance? They should not be static for all instances.

Thank you for any advice & constructive critics of this approach & proposals of other implementations.

Comment: For your second question: You can't. Management of the openmp threads is the job of the implementation. As a sidenote: Why do you need an implementation based on openmp? Have you looked at the (not yet official) [boost threadpool](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/)? Or maybe [Intel TBB](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/)?

Comment: I'm afraid OpenMP is not suited for such a task...

Comment: @Grizzly: Thanks. I'm aware of TBB and boost threadpool. But my project is the library for other developers and I can't easily introduce dependencies on those products. OpenMP would be nice because it does not require additional dependencies.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to guarantee that a certain object is self-contained and won't share threads with other OpenMP sections. OpenMP was not really designed with OOP in mind.

Comment: @nogard: As mentioned openmp is not really god for this task (you can't control the threads and have no option but to block on invocation). How about basing a threadpool on `boost::thread` (since your code already contains `boost::unique_future` I assume that this depency would be ok) or c++11 `std::thread`? Or even pthreads if nothing else is availible (wrapping those into a `std::thread` like interface is pretty straight forward).

Comment: @Grizzly: Thanks. Yes, sure, I can use boost threads in this project. I just wanted to check if it's possible with OpenMP.. Unfortunately it seems it's not the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to sum up: as described in the comments OpenMP is not an option for implementing generic thread pool or executor, because:

1. OpenMP is strictly a fork/join threading model.
2. You can't assign the owner for OpenMP threads
3. No control over threads and internal threadpool

Comment: OpenMP only requires you to fork once (the first call to "omp parallel").  That people tend to write forky-joiny programs with OpenMP is not a requirement of the standard.